# How much gas is exchanged in one human breath?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, respiration

When we breathe, our lungs absorb a portion of the oxygen in the air, and replace it with some amount of carbon dioxide and water vapor.  Typically, how much $O_2$ (in grams, milliliters, or moles for instance) is absorbed and how much $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ are released in one breath of a healthy adult?

Of course, the exact amounts will vary from person to person and based on how deeply the person is breathing, lung health, etc.  I'm just looking for a ballpark figure.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's a common error to believe that you're just breathing out CO2 and H2O. You're also breathing out a fair amount of oxygen as well.

Comment: @Jeremy  Indeed.  This is why CPR includes breathing for the recipient.  If it was just CO2 and H20, you wouldn't be doing much good!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_volume)

> "In a healthy, young adult, tidal volume is approximately 500 ml per inspiration..."

(tidal volume is the volume inspired/expired)

Using this figure, together with values for gas composition also [taken from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing#Breathing_in_gas), I estimate that in each breath we take in 18 mg O<sub>2</sub> (1.1 mmol) and we release 36 mg of CO<sub>2</sub> (1.2 mmol) plus 20 mg H<sub>2</sub>O (1.1 mmol). These are, as you say, ballpark figures.

Sample calculation:

O<sub>2</sub> inspired = 21% by volume; O<sub>2</sub> expired = 16% by volume

O<sub>2</sub> change = 5% by volume = 5*500/100 = 25 mL

1 mole gas = 22.4 L; 1 mmol gas = 22.4 mL

O<sub>2</sub> change = 25/22.4 mmol = 1.1 mmol

MW O<sub>2</sub> = 16

O<sub>2</sub> change = 17.6 mg

The relative values are reassuringly close to what you might predict from the textbook equation for oxidation of carbohydrate: C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub> + 6O<sub>2</sub> -> 6CO<sub>2</sub> + 6H<sub>2</sub>O

Comment: Thanks!  I guess all the figures I needed were on Wikipedia, but thanks for putting 'em together for me.  Fun fact: you lose about 1.5 pounds of weight per day just to breathing (since the CO2 and H2O are heavier than the O2; assuming 20K breaths/day).

Comment: @NathanReed, interesting point, but you have your numbers wrong. H2O is not heavier than O2. H2O is a single molecule of Oxygen with a couple of extra protons (H+). It will be lighter than O2.

Comment: @terdon I meant that the CO2 and H2O *combined* are heavier than the O2.

Comment: The textbook equation for respiration doesn't always hold. The molar ratios really depend on what is being metabolized by the organism, and that can depend on a number of factors including health and activity. For a more precise ratio you need to consider the respiratory quotient - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_quotient